# How to implement this feature in javascript ? Make uncertain , divorce, the wife say!

Tags: javascript, class, function, indexing

In the Javascript, could I define a class, the class itself can also when a function call, similar to the index, such as:

```
function A()
{
}

var a=new A();
var v=a();       //Use ordinary/like Javascript function use
```

Comment: .....what? I think you'll have to clarify this quite a bit, no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a abuse of the [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function) syntax (it will work without the new)

```
function A(message) 
{   
  return function(){alert("Make " + message);}
}

var a = new A("uncertain, divorce the wife say");
var v = a(); //Use ordinary/like Javascript function use
```

Comment: A +1 only because it works (on FF 3.6 at least). Dreadfully awful though.

Answer (score 0):

No,This instance "a" has no object "A" prototype

a instanceof A===false